# How can I automate the process of releasing the same iOS app with different branding?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store

Unique one but I'm sure there is a solution.

We run an app that will go onto be used by 100s of different businesses own customers.

A requirement for this is the app will need to appear in the App Store under different name + branding each time and every time.

The functionality within the app will be the same however it will be hitting different end points in places using different organisationIds.

How can we best make changes to this app such as adding features without uploading times to the app store?

Any recommendations?

We've had a look around at length but cannot seem to find a solution using Apples own products. Can't be the first to run into this surely. We specifically need this installed via the app store, can't just put the ipa file somewhere.

Comment: You should take a look at [Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/).

Comment: "You" probably can't publish all of these apps either.  You will need to work out a process by which you publish each version under the developer account if the relevant organisation. If you try and publish under your own developer account you will almost certainly be rejected for branding nit matching your company and for spamming the App Store.

Comment: @Paulw11 we are doing this for local authorities. Would this really be a problem with Apple?

Comment: Yes. You will be coming up again [4.3](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#spam) and possibly [4.2.6](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#minimum-functionality)

Comment: You might want to consider an approach where you publish a single app and the user is promoted to select their local authority on first launch. You can then download config from your server for that local authority.  The difficulty is you won't know if you will be rejected by Apple until you submit, which potentially means a lot of work for nothing.

Comment: @Paulw11 appreciate your response, our issue is everyday people need to be able to clearly find our app from the appstore. Legally we cannot use a generic app and a picker model.

Comment: Ok. I am just giving some advice of the challenges you are likely to face. Maybe Apple won't object. Maybe they will.

Comment: @AlexAndrew - realize that you are saying: *"We need to do something that Apple explicitly forbids... How can we do it?"*